# rails s or bundle exec rails s

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

In rails 3 does `rails s` invoke bundler so that you don't need to do `bundle exec rails s` or is `bundle exec` required to run `rails s` in your apps Gemfile environment?

***Update***
It's understood that `bundle exec` should be used before rake tasks because of different rake versions.  See http://railsapps.github.com/installing-rails-3-1.html for more details.  This question is about rails scripts, like:

```
rails s
rails server
rails c
rails console
```

^Should `bundle exec` be used before these rails scripts, or is bundler invoked by the rails command?

Comment: I always add `alias rails='bundles exec rails'; alias rake='bundle exec rake'` to my bashrc. Problem solved.

Comment: I don't think the `alias rails='bundle exec rails' is necessary: see:
[http://railsapps.github.com/installing-rails-3-1.html](http://railsapps.github.com/installing-rails-3-1.html)
&&
[http://yehudakatz.com/2011/05/30/gem-versioning-and-bundler-doing-it-right/](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/05/30/gem-versioning-and-bundler-doing-it-right/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should get this behavior in Rail >= 3.1 however you need to be careful because you may be using an older version of rake:

> It’s good practice to use the command bundle exec rake instead of rake
> so you’ll use the version of Rake specified in your gemfile (or a
> dependency specified in the Gemfile.lock file) instead of the default
> version. For example, instead of rake db:migrate, run bundle exec rake
> db:migrate.
>
> What You Need to Know: Make sure you are using Rake 0.9.2.2 (or newer)
> with gem update rake before installing Rails 3.1. And use bundle exec
> rake instead of rake.

Quoted from: http://railsapps.github.com/installing-rails-3-1.html

It looks like the opposite it true for the rails command:

> don’t run bundle exec before rails command, rails already checks the
> presence of Bundler through the Gemfile and sets up everything
> according to it without the overhead of bundle exec. rails command is
> the only exception to the rule.

Quoted from: https://www.wyeworks.com/blog/2011/12/27/bundle-exec-rails-executes-bundler-setup-3-times/

Comment: I understand that `bundle exec` is a good idea for rake tasks but what about for rails scripts like `rails server` or `rails console` ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion ... I've edited this answer to reflect the correct question.

Answer (score 1):

http://bundler.io/v1.5/rails3.html - "Rails 3 comes with baked in support with bundler...Bundler is transparently managing your dependencies!" So just run the server with

```
rails server
```