# Why is `bundle exec rails s` not the same as `rails s`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

Despite answers like these: [rails s or bundle exec rails s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617085/rails-s-or-bundle-exec-rails-s)

and blog posts like these: https://www.wyeworks.com/blog/2011/12/27/bundle-exec-rails-executes-bundler-setup-3-times/

which all seem to indicate you should simply run `rails s` rather than `bundle exec rails s` I still find that occasionally I can't simply run `rails s`. E.g.

```
$ rails s
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

$ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

Whereas running this immediately afterwards in the same environment:

```
$ bundle exec rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.0.beta1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-01-28 12:31:48] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-01-28 12:31:48] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-darwin14.0.0]
[2015-01-28 12:31:48] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=18959 port=3000
```

Why is it not the same? Should this behaviour be fixed and, if so, how?

==== UPDATE

In response to @awendt

```
$ which rails
/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin/rails
$ rails c
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
$ bundle exec rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.0.beta1)
2.0.0-p598 :001 >
```

Comment: its expected, aways use bundle exec to ensure you're using the proper context

Comment: Then shouldn't answers like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617085/rails-s-or-bundle-exec-rails-s be voted down? E.g. quoting: "don’t run bundle exec before rails command, rails already checks the presence of Bundler through the Gemfile and sets up everything according to it without the overhead of bundle exec."

Comment: if I understand the documentation correct, this behaviour was added in Rails 3, and only if you have the *require 'bundler/setup'* defined, which basically calls bundler then.

But I do not understand how this would work properly due the context mismatch....bundler documentation doesnt mention you shouldnt do this.

Comment: @SnowCrash Thanks for the update. Does `/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin/rails` match [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/railties/bin/rails) or is it different?

Comment: Very different. I have this: https://gist.github.com/0xsnowcrash/e1754695637637cd3f55

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to reproduce this, I get (on Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS):

```
me@machine:/some/path$ rails c
The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  To run 'rails' please ask your administrator to install the package 'rails'
me@machine:/some/path$ which rails
me@machine:/some/path$
```

So in my case, the rails script is not in my `$PATH`.

Your setup is different because the message explicitly mentions gems. You might even get this:

```
you@machine:/some/path$ which rails
/usr/bin/rails
you@machine:/some/path$
```

because `/usr/bin/` is in your `$PATH` somewhere before other things and [you're still invoking the rails script that ships with the OS](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/issues/73#issuecomment-2605773).

Anyway, the important part is: **`bundle exec rails c` lets Bundler figure out where to find the Rails gem, instead of letting the shell figure it out.**

You may install gem into a completely arbitrary location, *where only Bundler can find them* because that location is not in your `$PATH` but in your `$BUNDLE_PATH` (see [list of available keys for `bundle config`](http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/bundle-config.1.html#LIST-OF-AVAILABLE-KEYS)).

That's why `rails` and `bundle exec rails` are not the same.

This is not an error, and the behavior should not be fixed. Yes, you shouldn't have to run `bundle exec rails` because in recent versions, `rails` does the exact same thing. But the error you're seeing is a different issue.

Comment: I'm not clear. `which rails` *is* finding the Rails gem - see my Update.

Comment: @SnowCrash On your system, does `/usr/bin/rails` exist?

Comment: Yes. And checking the version: `$ /usr/bin/rails -v` gives `Rails 4.0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

For `Rails 3x` and above,whenever you are running the `rails server`,its always in **context** of the your `environment` and your `Gemfile`.So `bundler` helps in this regards to start and load the **required** gems/libraries using `$BUNDLE_PATH` for starting the application which by default wont be there if your are not using `bundle exec` instead it includes only the default libraries/gems using `gemset`(if you are using `rvm`) OR default path to load.

..hope this helps