# Why doesn't `rspec spec` work on cloned rails projects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I just installed Ruby and Rails, in Windows Subsystem for Linux (Ubuntu), through rbenv. I followed the [GoRails](https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10) installation guide and everything seems to work perfectly.

When I start a new project, `rails new myapp -T`, and initialize rspec `rspec --init`, and run some tests, `rspec spec`, everything works perfectly fine.

The problem I'm having is, when I cloned one of my rails projects from Github and ran `rspec spec`, I got this:

`/home/damianrivas/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:146:in 'to_app': missing run or map statement (RuntimeError)`

But when I try `bundle exec rspec spec`, everything works fine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617085/rails-s-or-bundle-exec-rails-s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bundle exec rspec spec` executes the command in the context of Bundler. This means that the version specified in the Gemfile is run and Bundler takes care of properly placing the gem in the load path.

`rspec spec` executes whichever `rspec` is in your path which might not be the correct version at all.

An alternative to running `bundle exec` is creating [binstubs](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/wiki/Understanding-binstubs):

```
bundle binstub rspec-core
```

This creates a "bundle wrapped" executable in the `bin` directory of the project.

You would then run RSpec with `bin/rspec`.

Comment: This makes sense! I'm fairly new to rails so I thought it had something to do with WSL. Thanks